# Почему элемент массива принимает значение?

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть такая программа. Должна получать на вход строку и методом хеширования записывать в массив.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class HashEntry {
private:
    int key;
    char value[32];
public:

    HashEntry(int key, char value[32]) {
        this->key = key;
        strcpy_s(this->value,value);
    }

    int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    char* getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    void setKey(int key)
    {
        this->key= key;
    }

    void setValue(char value[32]) 
    {
        strcpy_s(this->value, value);
    }
};



int hashFunc(char h[32])
{
    int l = strlen(h);
    int k = ((int)h[0] + (int)h[l-1])%100;
    return k;
}

int reHashFunc(int k)
{
    return(k*2)%100;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char* arr[100];
    char x[32];
    int b = 2;
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 99; i > 0; i--)
    {
        arr[i] = NULL;
    }

    do{
        cin >> x;
        if (arr[b] != NULL) cout << "arr[" << b << "]= " << arr[b] << endl;
        b = hashFunc(x);
        cout << "Hash function = " << b << endl;
        if (arr[b] == NULL) 
        { 
            arr[b] = x; cout << "Элемент записан, код - " << b << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (strcmp(arr[b], x) == 0)cout << "Такой элемент уже есть1" << endl;
            else{

                c = reHashFunc(b);
                cout << "Rehash function = " << c << endl;

                if (arr[c] == NULL)
                {
                    arr[c] = x; cout << "Элемент записан, код - " << c << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (strcmp(arr[c], x) == 0)cout << "Такой элемент уже есть2" << endl;
                    else{
                        while (c != b){
                            c = reHashFunc(c);
                            cout << "Rehash function = " << c << endl;

                            if (arr[c] == NULL){
                                arr[c] = x; cout << "Элемент записан, код - " << c << endl; break;
                            }
                            if (strcmp(arr[c], x) == 0){cout << "Такой элемент уже есть3" << endl; break;}
                        }
                        if (c == b){ cout << "Невозможно идентификатор"; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (arr[b] != NULL) cout  << "arr[" << b << "]= " << arr[b] << endl;
    } while (strcmp(x, "stop") != 0);

    do
    {
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        cin >> x;
        b = hashFunc(x);

        if (arr[b] != NULL) cout << "arr[" << b << "]= " << arr[b] << endl;
        else
        {
            c = reHashFunc(b);
            if (arr[c] != NULL) cout << "arr[" << c << "]= " << arr[c] << endl;
            else cout << "Нет такой";
        }

    } while (strcmp(x, "stop") != 0);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Вот в этом цикле почему-то значение arr[b] присваивается х -ом сразу после того как его вводишь. Не могу понять по какой причине это случается.

```
do{
        cin >> x;
        if (arr[b] != NULL) cout << "arr[" << b << "]= " << arr[b] << endl;
        b = hashFunc(x);
        cout << "Hash function = " << b << endl;
        if (arr[b] == NULL) 
        { 
            arr[b] = x; cout << "Элемент записан, код - " << b << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (strcmp(arr[b], x) == 0)cout << "Такой элемент уже есть1" << endl;
            else{

                c = reHashFunc(b);
                cout << "Rehash function = " << c << endl;

                if (arr[c] == NULL)
                {
                    arr[c] = x; cout << "Элемент записан, код - " << c << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (strcmp(arr[c], x) == 0)cout << "Такой элемент уже есть2" << endl;
                    else{
                        while (c != b){
                            c = reHashFunc(c);
                            cout << "Rehash function = " << c << endl;

                            if (arr[c] == NULL){
                                arr[c] = x; cout << "Элемент записан, код - " << c << endl; break;
                            }
                            if (strcmp(arr[c], x) == 0){cout << "Такой элемент уже есть3" << endl; break;}
                        }
                        if (c == b){ cout << "Невозможно разместить идентификатор"; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (arr[b] != NULL) cout  << "arr[" << b << "]= " << arr[b] << endl;
} while (strcmp(x, "stop") != 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это оттого, что вы присваиваете элементам значение указателя на один и тот же выделенный на стеке массив `x` вместо выделения нового буфера. Используйте лучше `std::vector<std::string>>`.

Comment: А есть возможность просто записать в элемент значение из массива?

Comment: Если только каждый раз динамически выделять новый массив, копировать в него данные и присваивать указатель на этот новый массив, не забывая в конце программы освободить память.

Comment: А можно освободить память из под элемента, объявленного в цикле, в конце программы? Просто если делать это в самом цикле то данные не сохраняются, а если объявлять массив вне цикла то возвращается первоначальная ошибка.

Comment: @ENTERF34R Можно, только главное не забыть это сделать.